# Cypress how to use api key in put/post request?

Tags: post, cypress, put, api-key

I am trying to use AWS API and its API-key in POST/PUT call in Cypress, couldn't find enough details, can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There are few options you can try, Here is one :

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/users*', (req) => {
  req.headers['x-api-key'] = 'bearer my-bearer-auth-token'
}).as('addAuthHeader')
```

Refer Offical Link here:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Assertions

Comment: Can you please put more details like how to use above in my cy.request? I tried using with cy.wait it didn't work for me

Comment: use cy.interecpt() , refer above the link for more details

Comment: Thanks @Umesh. I did use cy.intercept but code didn't work for me

Comment: @Showman Can you please paste the code and error details above i nthe question, it will be helpful

Comment: I was able to resovle it syntax is: header{authorization : key + value} no quotes –

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resovle it syntax is: authorization : key + value no quotes –

Comment: Provide the code for understanding purpose thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cy.request`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request). Although not outlined in the docs, it accepts an object:

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/',
  headers: { 'x-api-key': 'APIKEY' },
}).then((res) => {
  // use the response with response.body
});
```